# I can write to file but I cant read using ifstream in QT

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

In my program, the user collects points and at the end of the program the points are saved to a file if they are bigger than the smallest number of points in the file. For some reason, the program is not able to read the file so the value of the smallest int stays at zero. This means that it will still write to the file. For some reason, the write part of the program works while the read part doesn't. I have tested this code in code blocks and it worked just fine but I don't know why it doesn't work in QT.

```
std::ifstream myFile;
myFile.open("/scoreboard");
largest = 0;
smallest = 0;
myFile >> next;
while(myFile>>next)
{

    if(largest<next)
    {
        largest = next;
    }
    if(smallest>next)
    {
        smallest = next;
    }
}

if (points>smallest)
{
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open ("scoreboard", std::ios::app);
    myfile << "\n" << points << std::endl;
    myfile.close();
}


if (points>=largest)
{
    ui->textBrowser->setText("Your final score is " + QString::number(points) + " points. The highest score is " + QString::number(points) + " points, which was right now!");
}
else 
{ 
    ui->textBrowser->setText("Your final score is " + QString::number(points) + " points. The highest score is " + QString::number(largest) + " points.");
}
```

Comment: Is the file really in the root of your filesystem? This is discouraged in linux.

Comment: No, I made a resource file and in the resource file the file 'scoreboard' was under / so I was just trying that out to see if it would work

Comment: It should not work. QFile should work with QFile myfile("://scoreboard");` although you can read but not modify a resource.

Comment: I never used Qfile I'm using fstream

Comment: When you say resources, do you mean Qt resources (.qrc file)?

Comment: Yes I do mean qrt.

Comment: You can not modify the .qrc since at the end of the compilation this is part of the executable.